# How to use Python properties efficiently?

Tags: python, properties

Let's say I have a class `Foo` that stores some statistical data, and I want to encapsulate the access to these data using Python properties. This is particularly useful, for example, when I only store the variance of a variable and want to have access to its standard deviation: in that case, I could define the property `Foo.std` and make it return the square root of the variance.

The problem with this approach is that if I need to access `Foo.std` multiple times, I will calculate the square root each time; furthermore, since the notation of a property is exactly like that of an attribute, the user of my class might not be aware that a computation is taking place everytime the property is accessed.

One alternative in this example would be to calculate the standard deviation every time I update my variance, and set it as an attribute. However, that would be inefficient if I don't need to access it at every update.

My question is: what is the best approach to use a Python property efficiently, when you need to perform a costly calculation? Should I cache the result after the first call and delete the cache in case of an update? Or should I rather not use a property and use a method `Foo.get_std()` instead?

Comment: "Should I cache the result after the first call and delete the cache in case of an update?" You should do this regardless if providing by property or function.

Comment: If you want to tip the user about costly procedures, I would expose them as a function. Unless everything you do is similarly expensive or so fast you don't care.

Comment: Besides, I am not sure if your example is your real use case or not, but the existing standard that does exactly the same (numpy) uses functions for such behavior, so a lot of people will expect that.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Usually you can do this through *caching*. For example you can write:

```
class Foo:

    def __int__(self, also, other, arguments):
        # ...
        self._std = None

    @property
    def std(self):
        if self._std is None:
            # ... calculate standard deviation
            self._std = ...
        return self._std

    def alter_state(self, some, arguments):
        # update state
        self._std = None
```

So here we have a propert `std` but also an attribute `_std`. In case the standard deviation is not yet calculated, or you alter the object state such that the standard deviation might have changed, we set `_std` to `None`. Now if we access `.std`, we first check if `_std` is `None`. If that is the case we calculate the standard deviation and store it into `_std` and return it. Such that - if the object is not changed - we can later simply retrieve it.

If we alter the object such that the standard deviation might have changed, we set `_std` back to `None`, to force re-evaluation in case we access `.std` again.

If we alter the state of a `Foo` object twice before recalcuating the standard deviation, we will only recalculate it once. So you can frequently change the `Foo` object, with (close to) no extra cost involved (except setting `self._std` to `None`). So if you have a huge dataset and you update it extensively you only will put effort in calculating the standard deviation again when you actually need it.

Furthermore this can also be an oportunity to update statistical measures in case that is (very) cheap. Say for instance you have a list of objects that you frequently update in bulk. In case you increment all elements with a constant, then the *mean* will also increment with that constant. So functions that alter a state such that some metrics can easily be altered as well, might update the metrics, instead of making these `None`.

Note that whether `.std` is a property, or a function is irrelevant. The user does not have to know how often this has to be calculated. The `std()` function will guarantee that once calcuated, a second retrieval will be quite fast.

Answer (score 3):

Adding to Willem's answer: starting Python 3.8, we now have `functools.cached_property`. The official documentation even uses std and variance as examples. I'm linking the 3.9 documentation (https://docs.python.org/3.9/library/functools.html#functools.cached_property) since it has additional explanation on how it works.